# Rails - populating subcategory based on category selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to make a helper that provides a set of input values, for an attribute called :subcategory, based on the value of another attribute called :category.

I have a form which has:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <%= f.input :irrelevant, :as => :boolean, :label =>  "Is an ethics review required or applicable to this project?"  %>

    <%= f.input :category, collection: [ "Risk of harm", "Informed consent", "Anonymity and Confidentiality", "Deceptive practices", "Right to withdraw"], :label => "Principle",  prompt: 'select' %>

    <%= f.input :subcategory,  collection: text_for_subcategory(@ethic.category), :label => "Subcategory", prompt: 'select'  %>


    <%= f.input :considerations, as: :text, :label => "Identify the ethics considerations?",  :input_html => {:rows => 8} %>

    <%= f.input :proposal, as: :text, :label => "How will these considerations be managed?",  :input_html => {:rows => 8} %>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I then have a helper which has the input I want to use for :subcategory:

```
module EthicsHelper
    def text_for_subcategory(category)
      if @ethic.category == 'Risk of harm'
            [ "Physical Harm", "Psychological distress or discomfort", "Social disadvantage", "Harm to participants", "Financial status", "Privacy"]
        elsif @ethic.category == 'Informed consent'
            ["Explanation of research", "Explanation of participant's role in research"]
        elsif @ethic.category == 'Anonymity and Confidentiality'
            ["Remove identifiers", "Use proxies", "Disclosure for limited purposes"]
        elsif @ethic.category == 'Deceptive practices'  
            "Feasibility"   
        else @ethic.category == 'Right to withdraw' 
            "Right to withdraw from participation in the project"   
       end
    end  

end
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I want the category value to determine the values of the input field for subcategory.

When I try this, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `category' for nil:NilClass
```

**Controller**
I have a projects controller with the following actions:

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.ethics.build

   def show



end



  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
     @project.ethics_build unless @project.ethics
  end
```

Projects has many ethics and ethics belongs to project.

Comment: could you show your controller, especially the part where you're setting the `@ethic` instance?

Comment: You need to assign `@ethics` to  `@project.ethics_build unless @project.ethics`  in the show method too.  Check my updated answer. This should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you did wrong!
In the `text_for_subcategory(category)` method, you passed `category` into it but you are checking for  `@ethic.category` in your if statements. Rewriting it as it is below should work.

```
module EthicsHelper
  def text_for_subcategory(category)
    if category == 'Risk of harm'
        [ "Physical Harm", "Psychological distress or discomfort", "Social disadvantage", "Harm to participants", "Financial status", "Privacy"]
    elsif category == 'Informed consent'
        ["Explanation of research", "Explanation of participant's role in research"]
    elsif category == 'Anonymity and Confidentiality'
        ["Remove identifiers", "Use proxies", "Disclosure for limited purposes"]
    elsif category == 'Deceptive practices'  
        "Feasibility"   
    else category == 'Right to withdraw' 
        "Right to withdraw from participation in the project"   
    end
  end
end
```

Note that you already passed `@ethic.category` into the method when you called it in the form, so the `category` in the helper just acts as a placeholder.

So from the controller, `@ethics` was not set at all. In the `edit` method you need to set `@ethics` so it shows like the code below.

```
def show
  @ethics = @project.ethics_build unless @project.ethics
end
```

My assumption at this point is that you have set `@project` in a `before_action` method.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - I tried this, but I still get an error that says: undefined method `category' for nil:NilClass

Comment: could you show your controller, especially the part where you're setting the `@ethic` instance?

Comment: If it did not work, probably you are doing something wrong from your controller. Can you share your controller code too?

Comment: hi, I added the controller for projects, which is rendering ethics. Projects has many Ethics

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean about the before action. I have before_action :set_project in project controller. Do you mean that I should change the edit action in the ethics controller? or the projects controller? I render the ethics view as a partial in the projects show page.

Comment: Since this is a partial in projects#show, we should shift attention to the show method. Can you share the show action?

Comment: Hi again, thanks so much for the help. I tried this, but still get the error that says: undefined method `category' for nil:NilClass